# HTML form input type datetime-local result string missing seconds when picker seconds set to zero

Tags: php, html, datetime

I've got a form with an input produced as follows:

```
<?php echo '<input type="datetime-local" name="manualDateTime" value="'.$DateTimepicker.'" step=1><br>'.PHP_EOL; ?>
```

When I set the picker with Chrome to a non-midnight time I get the expected var dump result e.g.:

```
string(19) "2015-07-18T10:07:52"
```

However, if I set the picker to midnight, I get a shorter result missing the seconds:

```
string(16) "2015-07-17T00:00"
```

This wreaks havoc on subsequent code such as DateTime::CreateFromFormat and it appears that I'll need to code an exception for this.

Is there a way to ensure that the return string from a picker for a form input type of datetime-local will always have a consistent format?

Comment: My current work around is to remove seconds from the picker by removing the step=1 parameter in the form input and initializing it's value using a string without seconds. This seems to consistently produce results without seconds.